# List Oracle sequence object owners (homework)

Tags: sql, oracle

Write a SQL statement (not a DESCRIBE) to list the sequence owner and name for all of the sequence objects available to you.

Comment: What part confuses you?  Sequence Object?  Available to you?  What kind of statement you're supposed to write?  What parts of the system catalog you're supposed to query for this?  It helps if you provide at least *some* indication of what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: I am very new to oracle so the entire thing confused me. It looks like the answers given will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to figure out what a [sequence](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php) is. Then how to query for it in the [system tables](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2053.htm), the ALL_SEQUENCES table specifically. After that filtering the sequences for your own privileges should be easy.

Comment: Thank you for the link as I was looking for how to find these keywords and didn't know to look up "system tables".

Answer (score 1):

Since it's homework, here is a strong hint to get you started: Do an internet search for Oracle's `ALL_CATALOG`, `ALL_TABLES` and `ALL_TAB_COLS`.

Oracle, like most RDBMS, stores information about the structure & ownership of tables, objects, etc inside system tables. You will need to query the correct system tables to retrieve the information your instructor asked for.